# Transforming a `data.frame` using a character variable containing a string of data

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr, transformation, tibble

I have a `data.frame` that contains a character variable, which has a string of additional metadata (sort of a key-value format) that I'd like to have as variables in a `data.frame`; the metadata variable is riddled with nuances and inconsistencies: some of these metadata have multiple values (an array) of different length, not all observations have all of the additional data (would therefore need to be empty or `NA`), some metadata categories are repeated, or sometimes there are 'uncategorized' values preceding the more structured metadata (these can be ignored/dropped)

A better representative sample - note examples of the stated inconsistencies in `tags`:

```r
dat <- data.frame(title = c("How To", "Why To", "When To"),
                  id = c("001", "005", "102"),
                  tags = c("Type: Article,  Topics: solo, Length: 3.5, Topics: self help, DIY",
                           "case study, thinking, English, Type: Paper, Topics: philosophy",
                           "Language: EN, Type: Checklist, Topics: scheduling, time-management"))
```

The desired output would be a `data.frame` (or equivalent, like `tibble`) such as:

```r
#>           title          id   tags  Language        Type Length                             Topics
#>                 <chr>       <chr>  <chr>     <chr>       <chr>  <int>                        <chr>
#> 1        How To         001    ...        NA     Article    3.5               solo, self help, DIY
#> 2        Why To         005    ...        NA       Paper     NA                         philosophy
#> 3       When To         102    ...        EN   Checklist     NA        scheduling, time-management
```

NB: I've used `...` for shorthand representing the original string in `dat` ; I'm also using part of a provided solution before modifying the question to remove the "uncategorized" values via:
`gsub("(^.[^:]*, )(?=[[:alpha:]]+:)", "", tags, perl = T)`

A `tidyr` approach would be preferable but given my stitching together of various solutions from similar problems has only advanced me a little, any solution would be helpful

Comment: This is tricky because the commas sometimes mean "additional value for same metadata" and sometimes mean "new metadata header." There's probably an efficient way to distinguish those with regex (e.g. "phrase between comma and colon = header", but beyond my current knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work on the sample data, but there's probably a much shorter version with some regex that distinguishes between the two uses of comma.

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>%
  separate_rows(tags, sep = ", ") %>%
  separate(tags, into = c("header", "values"), fill = "left", sep = ": ") %>%
  fill(header, .direction = "down") %>%
  group_by(title, id, header) %>%
  summarize(values = paste(values, collapse = ", "), .groups = "drop") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = header, values_from = values)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 3 × 6
  title   id    Length Topics                      Type      Language
  <chr>   <chr> <chr>  <chr>                       <chr>     <chr>   
1 How To  001   3.5    self help, DIY              Article   NA      
2 When To 102   NA     scheduling, time-management Checklist EN      
3 Why To  005   NA     philosophy                  Paper     NA
```

---

Edit -- Using the updated data, here's a variation that treats Type as a special column. It's not clear to me how you want to treat language and tags vs. different Types for the same title, but I hope this indicates an approach you could adapt.

```
dat %>%
  separate_rows(tags, sep = ", ") %>%
  separate(tags, into = c("header", "values"), fill = "left", sep = ": ") %>%
  mutate(Type = if_else(header == "Type", values, NA_character_)) %>%
  fill(header, Type, .direction = "down") %>%
  filter(header != "Type") %>%
  group_by(title, id, Type, header) %>%
  summarize(values = paste(values, collapse = ", "), .groups = "drop") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = header, values_from = values)


# A tibble: 5 × 7
  title   id    Type      ` Topics` Length Topics                        Language
  <chr>   <chr> <chr>     <chr>     <chr>  <chr>                         <chr>   
1 How To  001   Article   solo      3.5    self help, DIY                NA      
2 When To 102   Checklist NA        NA     scheduling, time-management   NA      
3 When To 102   Paper     NA        NA     NA                            EN      
4 Why To  005   Article   NA        NA     case study, thinking, English NA      
5 Why To  005   Paper     NA        NA     philosophy                    NA
```

Comment: This works excellently, I don't know how all my searching did not land me to these `separate` functions in `tidyr` -- the only issue is now that I've returned to test this, I'm seeing just how wild the data is in "tags" and my sample data did not capture all the nuances .. updating the question and sample data to match

Comment: This accomplishes the goal - all metadata types are treated equally, goal was to transform from key:value string into variable/column format, therefore Type and Language (and Topics, and Length) are all just columns.  I employed the `group_by` a little later in the process to collapse repeated groups - the output of Topics in the sample data, such that there is a unique and single Topics column with all values (`solo, self help, DIY` in the first observation) - I also used [Leon Samson's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11856430/leon-samson) regex to great effect - thanks to you both!

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on the [answer from Jon Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73994481/11856430) but with a rexeg that distinguishes between the two uses of the comma:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>% 
  separate_rows(tags, sep = "(, )(?=[[:alpha:]]+:)") %>% 
  separate(tags, into = c("header", "value"), fill = "left", sep = ": ") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = header, values_from = value)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 6
#>   title   id    Type      Length Topics                      Language
#>   <chr>   <chr> <chr>     <chr>  <chr>                       <chr>   
#> 1 How To  001   Article   3.5    self help, DIY              <NA>    
#> 2 Why To  005   Paper     <NA>   philosophy                  <NA>    
#> 3 When To 102   Checklist <NA>   scheduling, time-management EN
```

The regex identifies all `,`  (comma with space) that are followed by one or more letters (`[[:alpha:]]+`, `+` means one or more), followed by a `:`.

If you want to keep the old tag, just add a line `mutate(old_tag = tags) %>%`  before the line with `separate_rows`

Comment: Thanks for this regex - it distinguishes the two uses as well as helped me to solve for the uncategorized/extraneous values as a cleaning step before the `separate` series of steps